# How to resolve CORS issues when querying Elasticsearch?

Tags: apache, docker, elasticsearch, cors

I am working on a software project and I am using Elasticsearch to support my search functionality. I have a server that I use to test with and I am using docker compose to create my cluster. Whenever I use my apps search bar (hosted via Apache on the same server as ES), I can never get the responses back due to CORS restrictions (I am getting around this using a Chrome extension, but I don't want users to have to install this to search).

I have tried enabled the proper http settings in the elasticsearch.yml file, but that doesn't seem to have done anything. I am using the Elasticsearch javascript module to make requests.

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    privileged: true
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.0
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    privileged: true
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
  elasticsearch3:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.0
    container_name: elasticsearch3
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    privileged: true
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    volumes:
      - esdata3:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.5.0
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200/
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
volumes:
  esdata1:
  esdata2:
  esdata3:
```

elasticsearch.yml:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: "X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization"
```

how I connect to ES (in javascript):

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'myServersIP:9200'
});
```

So when I go to my servers webpage (www.mydomain.com) I get my application, everything looks good. When I try to search, I get the COR issue and can't get any results back. I think this might be because I am connecting to my client via "myServersIP:9200" and not some proxied subdomain, but I am not sure. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong/how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try the one under C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config (windows case)

Edit it and add the CORS cofiguration (responsibly) as the "*" is quite dangerous

Hope this will help you